# How to test if import raises ImportError if package is missing?

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

I am writing a module which can have `pandas` as an optional pacakge. The import statement at the top of the file of `my_submodule.py` looks like this.

```
try:
    import pandas as pd
except (ImportError, ModuleNotFoundError):
    pd = None
```

Now I want to test that `pandas` is not installed and either `ImportError` or `ModuleNotFoundError` is raised.

How to do this?

At the moment my test file looks like this:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch

def test_no_pandas_import():

    with patch('sys.path', []):
        from my_module import my_submodule
        assert my_submodule.pd is None
```

but the assertion is not True, pandas is imported and there errors are not checked.

Comment: If the import fails due to either ImportError or ModuleNotFoundError then the variable *pd* will be assigned None. Surely you just need to test that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my system (where pandas is not installed) I have created exactly your file `my_submodule.py`, inside the package `my_module`.

I have introduced your test function `test_no_pandas_import()` into the followed test class (in the file `test_pandas_exception.py`):

```
class MyTestCase(TestCase)
```

So the test code becomes as below:

```
from unittest import TestCase, main
from unittest.mock import patch

class MyTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_no_pandas_import(self):
        with patch('sys.path', []):
            # ---------> Note the followed instruction <---------------
            with self.assertRaises(ModuleNotFoundError):
                from my_module import my_submodule
                assert my_submodule.pd is None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The main difference between my test code and your test code is that I have added the instruction:

```
with self.assertRaises(ModuleNotFoundError):
```

If I execute the test method `test_no_pandas_import()` in my system, it pass, but if I remove your instruction:

```
with patch('sys.path', []):
```

the test fails with the following output:

```
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_no_pandas_import (__main__.MyTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/stack_overflow/test_pandas_exception.py", line 10, in test_no_pandas_import
    assert my_submodule.pd is None
AssertionError: ModuleNotFoundError not raised

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

In this case the test fails because the Exception `ModuleNotFoundError` is not raised. The exception is not raised because it has caught inside your file `my_submodule.py`.

### Removing the exception catch

If I change the code in your file `my_submodule.py` so that it doesn't catch the exceptions I obtain the followed code:

```
#try:
import pandas as pd
#except (ImportError, ModuleNotFoundError):
#    pd = None
```

where remains only the `import`.

With the previous code I can use the followed test code (without the instruction `with patch('sys.path', []):`):

```
from unittest import TestCase, main

class MyTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_no_pandas_import(self):
        with self.assertRaises(ModuleNotFoundError):
            from my_module import my_submodule
            assert my_submodule.pd is None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If I execute the previous test code in my system (where `pandas` is not installed) the test pass and this proof that the `ModuleNotFoundError` is raised.